Tensor product of divided power algebras
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $X$ and $Y$ be strictly graded commutative $R$-algebras with a divided power structure, see Definition 6.1 here. The book "Homology of Local Rings" of Gulliksen and Levin states that there is a unique divided power structure on $X\otimes_R Y$ for which the canonical maps $X\rightarrow X\otimes_RY\leftarrow Y$ are maps of divided power algebras, see Proposition 1.7.10. This in particular implies the following: if $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ and both have positive even degrees, then $x^i\otimes y^{(i)}=x^{(i)}\otimes y^i$ where $i$ is a nonnegative integer. Indeed
$$ x^i\otimes y^{(i)}=(x^i\otimes1)(1\otimes y^{(i)})=(x\otimes1)^i(1\otimes y)^{(i)}=((x\otimes1)(1\otimes y))^{(i)}=((1\otimes y)(x\otimes 1))^{(i)}=(1\otimes y)^i(x\otimes1)^{(i)}=(1\otimes y^i)(x^{(i)}\otimes1)=x^{(i)}\otimes y^i,$$
where I have used Axiom 4 from Definition 6.1 and the fact that the canonical maps $X\rightarrow X\otimes_RY\leftarrow Y$ preserve divided powers.
My question is: can we prove the equality $x^i\otimes y^{(i)}=x^{(i)}\otimes y^i$ directly? Without using the result from the book of Gulliksen and Levin?
One can obviously do it in characteristic zero since
$$ x^i\otimes y^{(i)}=x^i\otimes \frac{y^i}{i!}=\frac{x^i}{i!}\otimes y^i=x^{(i)}\otimes y^i,$$
but in positive characteristic I do not see a way of proving this that does not go through the result of Gulliksen and Levin.
